# Нужны ли в этом предложении знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

**С видом наказания лишением свободы согласны?**

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его галочкой (она находится слева от ответа).

Answer (score 2):

> **С видом наказания лишением свободы согласны?**

Предложение лучше перестроить.

Вариант:

***С наказанием в виде лишения свободы согласны?***

Answer (score 1):

Можно тире с обеих сторон поставить: С видом наказания — лишением свободы — согласны? Или так сделать: С видом наказания "лишение свободы" согласны? Но лучше, конечно, перестроить предложение, чтобы оно нормально читалось.